# Getting data from DB2 via HIS using a.NET application

Tags: .net-core, db2, biztalk, mainframe

I'll need to work with a setup with existing IBM mainframe and Microsoft HIS 2016 already setup. If I want to get data from the DB2 into my own SQL (recurring flow, not a one-time migration), how should I go about it? 
I'm quite new to this solution and I'm not sure how to interface my .NET application with HIS. Will this require additional setup on the HIS, or is there a common way to do this? Any documentation or help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to use HIS? My idea would be to set up an ODBC connection to DB2 and communicate directly to the database...

Answer (score 1):

Completely the wrong tool to use for an extract and load.  Use ODBC and an ETL pipeline - either hand coded SQL or SSIS to transfer on a schedule between the mainframe and your SQL DB.

If you want to consume the information directly from IBM through BizTalk etc - that's when HIS comes into play.

Comment: Wouldn't that need something like a DB2 Connect license or something similar? If there is an HIS already setup, can't it be used instead?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, some clarification would help, thanks.